# Null point exception in persistent object , blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I am using persistent stores to store data in a Blackberry application. I am trying to store phone number in persistent objects, but after storing, it gives `null` value.

here i am posting my code:

```java
public static Vector push_data;
public static PersistentObject push_store = null;
public static final long KEY = 0x9df9f961bc333daL;

boolean isNumberVerified;
// PasswordEditField password;

static String verifiedPhoneNumber = "number";
public static String phoneNumber;
static String Number = "number";

public Third() {
    super(Field.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Field.FIELD_HCENTER);
    System.out.println("******************** Into SplashScreen");

    try {
        bitmap  = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("im.png");
        BitmapField bmpField = new BitmapField(bitmap);
        HorizontalFieldManager hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager();
        hfm.add(bmpField);`
```

........

```java
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (field == btnNext) {
            final String msg = Util.getRandomNumber();
            checkIsVerified(Number, msg);
        }
    }

    private void checkIsVerified(final String Number, final String msg) {
        Dialog.alert("Verifying  "  + Number);
        if (verifiedPhoneNumber == Number) {
            isNumberVerified = true;
            Dialog.alert("isverified  "  + Number);
            push_store = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject( KEY );
            push_data = (Vector) push_store.getContents();
            if( push_data == null ) {
                push_data = new Vector();
                push_data.addElement("number");
                push_store.setContents( push_data );
                push_store.commit();
                Dialog.alert("isverified  "  + push_data);

                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new spinner());
            } else {
                isNumberVerified = false;
                UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new Sms());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
public static String push_data="";
public static PersistentObject push_store; 
public static final long KEY = 0x9df9f961bc33352L;

//For get contents
push_store = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject( KEY );
push_data = (String) push_store.getContents();

//For set contents
push_data=Number;
push_store.setContents( push_data );
push_store.commit();
```

Comment: In the original code, `push_data` is a `Vector`, and `Number` is a `String`, so that won't work.  I assume they want to be able to store a vector of strings.

Comment: @Nate i know. But she/he doesnt tell anything about that.